# Struggling with .find() vs. .findOne() in my Meteor app

Tags: meteor, handlebars.js

I realize that this might be very close to other posts, but I just can't get this to stick in my head! :(  I need some help in trying to understand how to use `.find()` or should I be using `.findOne()`? *(so confused)* for a collection of mine.

**Goal:**
I want to get all of the documents out of the `People` collection and then for each document I want to create a new `<option>` where the `.name` is put in for text and the collection `._id` is the value.

---

### Here's some code:

**The Collection results from Mongo**

```
db.people.find()
{ "_id" : "1", "name" : "John" }
{ "_id" : "2", "name" : "Mike" }
{ "_id" : "3", "name" : "George" }
{ "_id" : "4", "name" : "Jane" }
```

**My Template Helper :**

```
Template.view_Admin_Staff.people = function() {
  console.log( 'people : ', People.find() );
  return People.find();

};
```

**My Template :**

```
            <select id="ddStaffID" name="staff">
                <option value="">-- Select One --</option>
                {{#each people}}
                    <option value="{{_id}}">{{name}}</option>
                {{/each}}
            </select>
```

---

My `console.log` found in the Helper returns `undefined`.  What in the world am I missing?

Comment: When you open the console in your browser, what does `People.find().fetch();` return? I'm assuming the "my template" code is for the `view_Admin_Staff` template.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Bloody-h3ll!  Warning to all us n00bs out there...one must subscribe to your publications in order for one to see and work with your publications. *sigh*

The code in my initial post is working as expected. I just simply forgot to subscribe to my exposing data in my publication in my client-side route.  `</foreheadSlap>`  I'm new enough to have doubted my query skills and didn't even thing to troubleshoot any further back in the code.  Thank you @Bozhao and @DavidWeldon for your quick replies.

Answer (score 1):

I am going to assume that your collection is People = new Meteor.Collectin('people');  And your template name for in the html is

When you did the console log in your template helper, you are logging the cursor itself, not the documents.  You can find out more about cursor at (https://www.eventedmind.com/tracks/feed-archive/how-do-client-cursors-work).

To see are you returning the correct data, you could .fetch method on a cursor.  Fetch will return an array of objects based on your query.  In your case, the query is empty, the fetch method should return everything that is available in the client's db.

To answer your question in the title.  both find and findOne are methods available on the Collection object.

find return a cursor. findOne return AN object, if there is a record matched to your query.

Comment: Thank you for the video feed.  I was wondering if there was some sort of screencast that would explain this better the the Meteor docs.  Cheers!